# How to remove imageView from effectView

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimageview, uivisualeffectview

How can I remove the `imageView` from `effectView`? Currently I am animating it in when the user loses an Internet connection. But I can't figure out how to remove the `imageView` once the connection is established. The `effectView` gets animated out but the image is still on the view. I tried using `removeFromSuperview()`, but most likely I didn't use it the right way.

```
func internetConnection() {
    let image = UIImage(named: "nointernet.png")
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image!)

    if reach.connection == .none {

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        imageView.center = self.effectView.center
        self.effectView.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        effectView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        imageView.alpha = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.effectView.effect = self.effect
            imageView.alpha = 1
            imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    }else{
        effectView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
            imageView.alpha = 0

            self.effectView.effect = nil

        }) { (Bool) in
            imageView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the connection comes back, you create a new image view and then attempt to remove the new image view. But you need to remove the existing image view. Update your code to get access to the existing image view in the `effectView` and remove it.

```
func internetConnection() {
    if reach.connection == .none {
        let image = UIImage(named: "nointernet.png")!
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        imageView.center = self.effectView.center
        imageView.alpha = 0

        self.effectView.contentView.addSubview(imageView)
        effectView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            self.effectView.effect = self.effect
            imageView.alpha = 1
            imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }
    } else {
        if let imageView = self.effectView.contentView.subviews.last as? UIImageView {
            effectView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
                imageView.alpha = 0

                self.effectView.effect = nil
            }) { (finished) in
                imageView.removeFromSuperview()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One only potential issue. Make sure that `internetConnection` isn't called twice in a row when the connection is lost. Otherwise you will end up adding multiple image views to the effectView.

Comment: thanks it works but when I scroll and turn off the wifi the image disappears.

Comment: Do some debugging. See what is happening in those conditions. Narrow down the problem. If you can't find the cause after doing some debugging, post a new question specific to that issue and include relevant code and details from your attempts to debug the problem.